# Quartz scheduler and Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I am refering to an example from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/):

When I execute the App.java, I am not able to see any output on the console.  The Eclipse console only shows:

> Sep 18, 2013 12:53:32 PM
>   rg.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1113708:
>   startup date [Wed Sep 18 12:53:32 IST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
>   Sep 18, 2013 12:53:32 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [spring-quartz.xml] Sep 18, 2013 12:53:32 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
>   preInstantiateSingletons INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1a33d48:
>   defining beans [runMeTask,runMeJob,simpleTrigger]; root of factory
>   hierarchy

Can someone help me to get this resolved? I am using spring 3.1.2 and quartz 1.8.6  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What issue are you having exactly?

Comment: Without seeing the context or any explanation of your expected behavior vs actual behavior it is hard to help. They output does not show any errors so it appears that your Spring context started properly.

Comment: Could you show some of your code, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that it's not a problem related to direct `System.out` printing to console,
you could replace the `System.out.println` in `RunMeTask` in the original example by (maybe depending on the logging framework you're using) `log.info(..)`

I've seen developers using eclipse console plugins to filter console output, particularly with logging output. So if that's the case, or if you're actually watching a log file, with `log.info` you're almost sure to have this message in the same place as Spring's INFO messages.
Logging is generally a good idea to see different stages of application initialization clearer, particularly when deployed to a customer's system where direct debugging is not an option. However, you want to use finer log levels than INFO in most cases.